# Multiple OnPause in one Activity (extend/implement second class)

Tags: java, android

I am working on an big Android-Project and have some problems, to organize my code and split the logic in seperate classes.
For example my MainActivity contains all the Logic to handle incoming GPS, NFC and QR Code-Events. All this Events have their own onStart(), onResume() and onPause() Logic and i want to outsource them into a new class and just implement or extend them, but it is not possible to extend more than one class.

How can i solve this organisation issue? Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, SensorListener, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // instantiate tabs
    // instantiate gps
    // instantiate rotation sensor
    // instantiate nfc
    // instantiate wifi hotspot
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // start nfc if necessary
    // start gps if necessary
    // start wifi hotspot if necessary
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // stop nfc if necessary
    // stop gps if necessary
    // stop wifi hotspot if necessary
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a ListenerHandler class (or individual ListenerHandler classes for each Listener) and then instantiate the handler(s) within your MainActivity.

eg, with one ListenerHandler class handling all listeners, your Main Activity would look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ListenerHandler listenerHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listenerHandler = new ListenerHandler();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    listenerHandler.onResume();
}

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    listenerHandler.onPause();
}
```

Then all the individual instructions would go in the ListenerHandler class, keeping the MainActivity class tidy. Your MainActivity would then not need to implement the listeners at all -- all those implementations could be handled in the handler class.

Comment: This is a great Idea!
Thank you very much